# Ember: simple way to set focus in a field

Tags: ember.js

I am looking for a simple way to set focus into a textfield or textarea.  I prefer not to mix Jquery syntax with Ember syntax ... and I prefer not to create seperate views for each textfield or textarea in which I ever want to set the focus.

Any suggestions ?

My textArea field is simply:

```
{{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="body" placeholder="body"}}
```

Thanks
Marc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straightforward way to set the focus on a `TextArea` would be the following:

```
App.FocusTextArea = Ember.TextArea.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.$().focus();
  }
});
```

And the whenever you want such a view you can use it like so:

```
{{view App.FocusTextArea valueBinding="body" placeholder="body"}}
```

> and I prefer not to create seperate views for each textfield or textarea in which I ever want to set the focus.

By creating a custom `TextArea` view which extends from `Ember.TextArea` you are not creating each time a new view, you are reusing the custom view with the desired behavior.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Clear and rather simple solution Thx. Marc

Answer (score 6):

With new Ember CLI you get this using simply `autofocus="autofocus"` in template *.hbs

```
{{input value=text type="text" name="text" placeholder="Enter text" autofocus="autofocus"}}
```

Comment: Works great, thx. One oddity is that it doesn't work if the input is empty to begin with.

Comment: Another oddity is if the input is inserted into the dom, removed, and inserted again the second time it's inserted it doesn't autofocus.

Comment: this simply proxies the attribute to the html element [input#autofocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autofocus) which depends on the DOMContentLoaded event. Which is why it only happens for the input once the first time, until you load the page

Comment: RE: "This doesn't seem to be working in 2.13" - to be more specific, I have a 'register' route(input autofocuses) then transition to 'login' route where there is a similar input (different name/id)(doesn't autofocus)

Answer (score 1):

This little package goes a step further and does this a slight bit more elegantly, directly in the template, without any further coding or subclassing:

```
<body>
  <!-- all the libraries -->
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.2.0/ember.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://rawgithub.com/AndreasPizsa/ember-autofocus/master/dist/ember-autofocus.min.js"></script>
  <!-- your template -->
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    Hello, world! {{ input }}
    :
    : more elements here
    :
    {{ autofocus }} {# <<<<< does the magic #}
  </script>
  <!-- your app -->
  <script>
    Ember.Application.create();
  </script>
</body>
```

You can get it from https://github.com/AndreasPizsa/ember-autofocus
or with `bower install ember-autofocus`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `component` that wraps the `input` field and use the `didInsertElement` hook to *focus* the inner `input`:

In the template:

```
// template.hbs
{{#focus-input}}
  {{input type="text"}}
{{/focus-input}}
```

Your component:

```
// components/focus-input.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement () {
    this.$('input').focus();
  }
});
```

Comment: It sure would be nice to just do something like `{{input id="id" initially-focused}}` or something. I guess you could extend the input helper to skip the nesting.

Answer (score 0):

in my case this helps
https://github.com/ember-a11y/ember-component-focus

component.coffee

```
import FocusableComponent from 'ember-component-focus/mixins/focusable-component'
export default Ember.Component.extend FocusableComponent,
  actions:
    show: () ->
      @set 'AddCardMode', true
      @focusAfterRender "#1"
```

template.emblem

```
if AddCardMode
  something input id=1
```